# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin Service Unavailable

Tags: rest, jenkins, artifactory

I try to setup the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin to deploy some artifacts after a successfull build.

But the configuration "Test Connection" button in the system configuration tab fails with "Service Unavailable".

This Rest Call is working!
`curl -uadmin:password "127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory/api/system/version"`

I don't know whats wrong here.

Comment: Do you have proxy server between Jenkins and Artifactory?
If so, go to the general settings of Jenkins, scroll to the Artifactory settings, press on "Advance" and check the "bypass proxy" checkbox.

Comment: Yes it was indeed a proxy problem. I thought localhost is on a whitelist to bypass that proxy by default. But it wasn't.

Comment: Great.  Happy I could assist.